# Using Extjs 5 & OpenLayers 3

Tags: geojson, openlayers, ext-js, geoext-2

To consume geojson data from a REST HAL CORS webservice, in client side i'm using ExtJs 5, but to map data having geometries i'm stuck between choosing geoExt2 which has a branch based on extjs5 and openlayers 2.3, or working directly with extjs5 and openlayers 3, for consuming data till the moment i'm using `rest` proxy in extjs, but geoext proxy seems not to be agile because it's based on `OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP` which do not support REST, is there any suggestions how to use extjs5 and ol3 with `rest`.

Answer (score 1):

With OL3, it is quite easy to read GeoJSON, using `ol.source.Vector`.

I'm using `Ext.direct`, but it is the same pattern if you use the regular `Ext.Ajax.request` call. On the callback, you use the `readFeatures` method.

To read a GeoJSON layer:

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
            Server.Plantas.Pedidos.asGeoJson({
                gid: 0
            }, function (result, event) {
                if (result.success) {
                    if (result.data.features) {
                        var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(result.data);
                        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('Problem', result.message);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    var vectorJSON = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorJSON);
```

On the server side, I use a SQL query to return the GeoJSON from the database:

```
    var sql = '';
    sql += 'SELECT row_to_json(fc) as geojson ';
    sql += "FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features ";
    sql += 'FROM ( ';
    //-- query
    sql += "SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lgeom.pretensao)::json As geometry, row_to_json(lprop) As properties ";
    sql += 'FROM plantas.pedidodetail As lgeom ';
    sql += 'INNER JOIN ( ';
    sql += 'SELECT id, gid FROM plantas.pedidodetail ';
    sql += 'where gid = ' + gid;
    sql += ' ) As lprop ';
    sql += 'ON lgeom.gid = lprop.gid ';
    //-- fim de query
    sql += ') As f )  As fc';
```

To write the features back to the database, I use the `writeFeatures` like:

```
            var features = printrequestdetaillayer.getSource().getFeatures();

            if (features.length) {
                var details = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).writeFeatures(features);
                Server.Plantas.Pedidos.saveGeoJsonDetail({
                    pedido: result.data[0].gid,
                    features: details
                }, function (result, event) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        console.log('Ok', result.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not ok', result.message);
                    }
                });
            }
```